# Import XML in MySQL with Sequel PRO or phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductData version="2.0">
  <Product>
    <code>1000001</code>
    <name>The Name</name>
    <brand>The Brand</brand>
    <category>The Category</category>
    <specification>
      <characteristic>
        <color>The Color</color>
        <size>The Size</size>
      </characteristic>
    </specification>
    <quantity>
      <store1>0</store1>
      <store2>4</store2>
      <store3>5</store3>
      <store4>2</store4>
      <store5>3</store5>
    </quantity>
  </Product>
</ProductData>
```

How do I create a table in my database and be able to import this data, since I have more than 100 `<Product>` and it is impossible for me to put one by one.

It is also necessary not to include some fields in my database, in fact I only need the code and the quantities of each store.

You can help me, I do not know **how to create the structure of the database** and I do not know how to do the **query to insert and then update**.

Comment: Please check this example "http://www.webslesson.info/2017/09/how-to-insert-xml-data-into-mysql-table-using-php.html" for xml  to phpmyadmin  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is closely related to (or maybe even a duplicate of) [XML file to a PHPMyAdmin Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197287/xml-file-to-a-phpmyadmin-database)

Basically, XML isn't a good way to get data in and out of phpMyAdmin because the schema that phpMyAdmin is expecting isn't what you have here. In the linked answer, I've provided some basic syntax example, but for best results you might want to create a test table and export it from your own phpMyAdmin to view some more intricacies of the schema. If you can make your data conform to that schema then the import should go smoothly.

I would either process the xml file with some other tool to remove the fields that you don't want or do the full import (to a temporary database if it makes it easier) and then drop the columns you don't need.

Comment: ok thank you very much for the information, I take it into account to proceed ... Greetings!